Query data cannot be undefined. Please make sure to return a value other than undefined from your query function. Affected query key: ["projects"]
Hago uso de useQuery donde deseo mostrar los productos que obtenga de la API.
const { data } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["projects"],
  queryFn: getProjects,
});

En un doc aparte tengo la función de getProducts.
En api('projects') hago referencia a un archivo aparte donde esta toda la URL de la api agregando al final /projects.
El metodo POST si funciona pero en el metodo GET me sale ese error en la consola del navegador y mi conexión en la terminal del servidor se crashea.
Error:
Query data cannot be undefined. Please make sure to return a value other
than undefined from your query function. Affected query key: ["projects"]

Código:
export async function getProjects() {
  try {
    const { data } = await api('/projects')
    const response = dashboardProjectSchema.safeParse(data)
    if (response.success) {
      return response.data
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (isAxiosError(error) && error.response) {
      throw new Error(error.response.data.error)
    }
  }
}


Ya checaste si regresa algo?  Luego noto que usas " " en lugar de ' '

Algo tarde, pero si le sirve a alguien:
En mi caso resultó ser un problema entre el hot reload del debugger en VS Code y react-query, por algún motivo los response de las peticiones se quedan en 'undefined' (motivo de la excepción que marca) aunque devuelvan datos y lo solucioné haciendo un reload completo cada que modificaba el código donde uso useQuery.
